# Из Delphi 7 ibx константы на Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, interbase

ibx компонент
В дельфи 7 код данный работает

```
params.values[ DPBConstantNames [ isc_dpb_user_name ] ] := DBUserName;
```

определен

```
DPBConstantNames: array[1..isc_dpb_last_dpb_constant] of string;
```

в дельфи 10.1 berlin определен

```
    DPBConstantNames : TDPBConstantNames;
TDPBConstantNames = TDictionary<string, integer>;
```

и код не работает выдается ошибка

```
[dcc32 Error]  E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Integer'
```

как исправить? Не писать же

```
params.values[ 'user_name' ] := DBUserName;
```

Comment: А isc_dpb_user_name какой тип в Delphi 10.1 имеет?

Comment: integer  как и в delphi 7

Comment: А вы не путаете местами key value в `TDictionary<string, integer>;`?

Comment: в том то все и дело, в  исходнике ibx компонента, установленного  в delphi xe10 так и написано  <string, integer>, причем у меня установлен еще и дистрибутив xe7 там аналогично.

Comment: это ibx компонент в дистрибутиве delphi

Comment: unit IBX.IBDatabase;

Answer (score 0):

```
TDPBConstantNames.ToArray[isc_dpb_user_name].Key
```

или

```
TDPBConstantNames.Keys[isc_dpb_user_name]
```